# What is wrong with my page.php?

Tags: page-template

I hard coded the html from resources.php from  a site into page I created the wordpress admin, which used the default page template. Then I entered the following code into the page.php template. The result is http://strategichospitalitysearch.com/blog/resources.

```
 <!-- Start Page Content -->         
 <h1 class="blog-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

     <?php 
     $page_id = 98; 
     $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); 
     $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
     $title = $page_data->post_title; // Get title
     echo $content; // Output Content
     ?>   
 <!-- End Page Content -->
 </div> 

 <!--End Main Content -->

</div>
<!-- End Container -->
```

My Problem is that it may not work for other pages in the future and the subpages for resources. What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 3):

if i understand right the problem is that you assign a static $page_id = 98; 
so no matter what page you go to it will only display that page's content.

what  you need is to use the WordPress loop so change your code to this

```
<!-- Start Page Content -->         
 <h1 class="blog-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php 
     if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :  the_post();
          the_content();
       endwhile;
     endif;    
 ?>   
 <!-- End Page Content -->
 </div> 

 <!--End Main Content -->

</div>
<!-- End Container -->
```

this why you get the same results but it will  work on all pages.